# Spyder fails to launch with psutils ImportError - Windows Anaconda

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, spyder

I'v been having a issue were Spyder has been failing to launch from the Anaconda Navigator. I launched my environment with a terminal and ran `spyder` and I'm getting a ImportError. 
[image: Import Error]

I'v uninstalled Anaconda multiple times and still no dice.

**[Here are](https://gist.github.com/abrad1212/503aeea77ca8c940ce7183e64f8fe5f9)** all my conda packages listed with `conda list > list.txt`
and **[here are](https://gist.github.com/abrad1212/53075a02e5ed25c95d40f195d4b58596)** all my pip packages listed with `pip freeze > requirements.txt`

EDIT:
Here is my PYTHONPATH
[image: Environment Variables]

Comment: What spyder version are you running?

Comment: I am using the latest version 3.2.0

Comment: Weird, I only remember seeing this issue pre 3.1.4

Comment: Is any of this being done through a zip?

Comment: I do not know, how should I check

Comment: Check if anything you are running (or try to run) has not been extracted.

Comment: I'm sorry. but I do not know what you mean. Should I check my Anaconda folder?

Comment: Anything that you are trying to run/running, yes.

Comment: I found spyder.exe in Anaconda3/Scripts and it started

Comment: Great! Is it working then?

Comment: Well no the spyder.exe in the Scripts folder is, but I cannot launch it with my conda environment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151542/discussion-between-abrad1212-and-liam-healy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing this issue my removing Anaconda and every Python installation on my machine as well the Python environment variables.

I fixed it by getting mad thinking how about removing every python and just reinstalling Anaconda. :D